# Div to stay in the center of page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJLeT.png)

I am new to CSS, how i can make the div stay at the center of the page like this?

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Lxk.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 center-block">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="MainCharacter" src="../Images/test_character.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS similar to this:

```
.container{
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

A possible problem is that this code will apply to all `.container`'s and `.rows`. You could add an id to them and select it using that id.